# WEBLOGIC : Using jar in EAR file instead of domain/lib

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am trying to use a new version of ehcache in my EAR file but there is an older one in the domain/lib folder of the weblogic server.

Of course it's not possible to upgrade the one in the domain/lib folder because it's used in other EAR files.

Is there a way to use the one inside my EAR file.

I tried to use :

```
<prefer-application-packages>
```

And

```
<prefer-application-resources>
```

In the weblogic-application.xml without success. It seems that the jar used is the one in the domain/lib folder.
I am trying to use ehcache with spring and I am using spring within a library deployed in weblogic.

Right now we are using WEBLOGIC 10 and we will use WEBLOGIC 12 in a few weeks.

Any ideas to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case it was not working because I used Spring from a library deployed in my weblogic.

So Spring was not able to use the Ehcache JAR in my EAR because Spring was not in my EAR. I removed the use of this Spring library and included all the Spring JARs in my EAR to make it work.